# shell script how to grab multi lines by passing a variable

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

sample.txt file contents are

```
pool abc {
        members {
            bc:x {
                address 1.2.3.4
            }
            cc:x {
                address 5.6.7.8           }
        }
        monitor x
    }
    pool cc {
        members {
            bc:x {
                address x.x.x.x
                state up
            }
        }
        monitor x
    }
```

From the above sample.txt file I want to collect some specific data - Conditions are

a. It should be inside pool abc braces. i.e pool abc {....}

b. The data is ip address - mentioned inside as address x.x.x.x

e.g when passing value "abc" as a variable value, output should be :

```
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
```

Note - Here "abc" is a value of a variable that needs to be passed to script doing the above-mentioned task.
I have tried regex as : `cat sample.txt | grep -P "abc {([\S\s]*)}"` --does not work

with sed and awk could not apply logic.

Comment: Could you please do checky solution and lemme know if this helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk` and with provided samples only.

```
var="abc"
awk -v var="$var" -v pool="pool" -v RS="" '
match($0,pool " " var".*}$"){
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i=="address" && $(i+1)~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/){
      print $(i+1)
    }
  }
}
' Input_file
```